# How to implement Confirmation Message in c# checkedListbox ItemCheck on Unselect an Item

Tags: c#, winforms, confirmation, checkedlistbox

When User clicks NO then the checkedListBox1 Item will be unchecked anyway, what is the right way to implement such a confirmation?

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.NewValue.ToString() == "Unchecked")
            {
                //Confirmation
                if (MessageBox.Show("Really Remove?","Remove", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,             MessageBoxIcon.Question,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) ==             System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
                {
                    return;
                }
}
```

Comment: Using return does nothing useful.  To cancel a check you need e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue.  Do strongly avoid spamming the user with "are you sure" boxes, accidental clicks should always be easy to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below :

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                var result = MessageBox.Show("Really Remove?", "Remove", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
                if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
                {
                    e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
                }
            }
        }
```